# Document compiles with pdflatex but not lualatex but why?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex

Using the current TexLive 2015 on Windows 7 I can successfully compile the following MWE with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12} 

\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Compiling the same document with lualatex on the other hand leads to the following error message:

```
This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.80.0 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (rev 5238)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
(./error_minimal.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files 
[...]
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luatexbase/luatexbase.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/ctablestack/ctablestack.sty
(c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.tex
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
\relax
l.140 \newcatcodetable\catcodetable@initex

?
```

Is this a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No problem here using TeX Live2015 on Ubuntu. Doing a general update now to check if that breaks it.

Comment: What is the date of the format?

Comment: Looks like you have an unpatched `2015/01/01` kernel: this is unfortunately buggy , which shows up with newer LuaTeX support. Ideally you should have either the `2015/01/01 PL2` or (better) the `2015/10/01 PL1` kernel.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: The `luatex.fmt` is 2 hours old and the size is 529 kB.

Comment: this looks like https://github.com/josephwright/ltluatexsupp/issues/5 (which was fixed by rebuilding/updating the formats)

Comment: @Alexander that time is when you built it but you are showing `LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>` there have been 3 latex releases since then.

Comment: I didn't meant the build date but the format date. With `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1` your example works fine.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you, that seems to be the same issue. After rebuilding everything using `fmtutil-sys --all` the format shows `patch level 1` and everything works again.

Comment: @Alexander OK , although your system is not updating the format for some reason, it's odd that you have ltluatex but do not have latex 2015/10/01 from this month which was released at exactly the same time.

Comment: If you look at `c:/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx` what do the lines around 696 say, since you have ltluatex I would expect them to say `\edef\fmtversion
   {2015/10/01}
\def\patch@level{1}`  but if that is the case the format you are using is older and has been made from some other files. Do you have a second local tex tree?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is exactly what the file contains: `\edef\fmtversion
   {2015/10/01} \def\patch@level{1}`. The output from above was before I ran `fmtutil-sys --all`. I still have an old TeXLive 2014 installation in parallel but this should just be sitting idle on the disk.

Comment: but if you run your document now does it say 2015/01/01 patch level 1 or 2015/10/01 patch level 1 ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 1`. So I am happy now and can continue :)

Comment: @Alexander yes still a bit worrying that two people now have hit that, something is making tlmgr fetch the latest files but not rebuild the formats using them. But it's not _your_ problem any more:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an issue with the (short lived) 2015/01/01 format it should be OK with  2015/01/01 patch level 1 and is definitely OK with the current 2015/10/01 patch level 1 release.