# code produces error with lualatex but not with pdflatex. Why?

Tags: luatex

I try to use tufte-book and can compile with pdflatex but not with lualatex (which I would prefer to use). The errors are

```
25: Argument of \MakeUppercase has an extra }. }{AF}
25: Paragraph ended before \MakeUppercase was complete. }{AF}
25: You can't use `\relax' after \the. }{AF}
25: Use of \__text_expand_space:w doesn't match its definition. }{AF}
25: Undefined control sequence. }{AF}
25: Missing number, treated as zero. }{AF}
25: Missing { inserted. }{AF}
25: Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed. }{AF}
25: Missing } inserted. }{AF}
28: Argument of \MakeUppercase has an extra }. \maketitle
28: Paragraph ended before \MakeUppercase was complete. \maketitle
28: You can't use `\relax' after \the. \maketitle
...
```

My attempts at checking give matching opening and closing braces, and I cannot find `\MakeUppercase` in the code.

Why does this code not work with lualatex? I have checked [lualtex docs](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/info/luatex/lualatex-doc/lualatex-doc.pdf) and [a perhaps related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/frequently-loaded-packages-differences-between-pdflatex-and-lualatex), but not found an answer. I use

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.15.0 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)  
(format=lualatex 2023.6.17)  27 JUN 2023 21:03
 restricted system commands enabled.
```

and think [this similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/272953/document-compiles-with-pdflatex-but-not-lualatex-but-why) does not apply.

A MWE is:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% Book metadata
\title{Ein Buch mit Titel}

% Prints an epigraph and speaker in sans serif, all-caps type.
\newcommand{\openepigraph}[2]{%
  %\sffamily\fontsize{14}{16}\selectfont
  \begin{fullwidth}
  \sffamily\large
  \begin{doublespace}
  \noindent\allcaps{#1}\\% epigraph
  \noindent\allcaps{#2}% author
  \end{doublespace}
  \end{fullwidth}
}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\vfill
\openepigraph{%
Was soll man tun?
}{AF}
\vfill

\maketitle

% Start the main matter (normal chapters)
\mainmatter

Here the main matter

\end{document}
```

Comment: try with `\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\allcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[200]{#1}}%
\renewcommand{\smallcapsspacing}[1]{\textls[50]{#1}}%`

Comment: works immediately - thank you! any explanation possible?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: i have set a pull request to tufte-latex (that is where it goes) and would like to have a brief hint to why this is required. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I added a comment to your pull request.

Comment: thank you - now I understand a bit more. I hope it can be fixed!